# Apple Enterprise Distribution Certificate Revoked

Tags: ios, certificate, enterprise

I managed to accidentally revoke an enterprise distribution certificate. My Apps are deployed using an MDM. All these apps have stopped working. Is there any way to get these apps working again without rebuilding using a new certificate and redeploying.
I am in a real mess here and it will take me days to recover. Any help, suggestions, assistance will be rewarded.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I thought I'd answer it in case it helps others.  You probably now know that unfortunately once a certificate has been revoked you will have to create a new certificate and then either edit or create a distribution profile to point to that certificate.  You'll then have to rebuild and deploy using the updated/new provisioning profile.